# Logic counterexample to argument

Tags: logic

$\sim \forall x \; (M(x) \vee W(x))$
$\exists x \; \sim M(x)$

---

$\exists x \; \sim W(x)$

This argument is invalid, could any one please provide a counterexample?

The first two lines are the premise, the sentence after the gap is the conclusion

Comment: Are you using $\sim$ as negation?.

Comment: Are you sure it's invalid? It seems valid to me.

Comment: Yes ~ is a negation.

Comment: Could you also explain what this argument means, the first premise in words. Thank you

Comment: I think that we do not need a theorem prover to check it ! the first statement is simply $\exists x (\lnot M(x) \land \lnot W(x))$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Fitch proof (it's ugly and long partly because I had to prove instances of quantifier equivalence and De Morgan laws). I have broken it down into small steps. The premises are (1-2):

[image]

To transform (1) to the equivalent formula $\exists x\lnot(M(x) \lor W(x))$, we proceed as follows (3-13):

[image]

We then 'De Morgan' (13) into the equivalent formula $\exists x (\lnot M(x) \land \lnot W(x))$ as follows: (14-28):

[image]

Finally, we use (28) to get the desired conclusion (29-32):

[image]

---

Mauro is right of course, none of this is necessary. Bill's and Quinn's arguments are equally satisfactory. You asked for a Fitch derivation, so I typed this up.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the proof but is step 3 a legitimate move? I am unable to find that anywhere online.

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll prove that step instead of hoping that your teacher allows it.

Comment: @user148006 I've updated the answer. Let me know if you find something unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your help but is there anyway this entire proof could fit into one? I just need to submit one file, some argue that this is actually an invalid argument so i am kinda confused.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'll put it all together; will look ugly.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it in the morning.

Answer (score 4):

This argument is actually valid. Let $M(x)$ denote "$x$ is a man" and $W(x)$ "$x$ is a woman". The first premise says that it is not the case that everyone is a man or a woman; in other words there is someone who's neither man nor woman. So even without the second premise, the conclusion, which says there is someone who's not a woman, must hold. (Whoever is neither man nor woman must, in particular, not be a woman.)

Comment: If i were to make a proof of it using fitch, how would i go about doing it? I was under the impression that this argument was invalid.

Comment: @user148006 I'm not familiar with fitch, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

$\sim \forall x \sim$ is equivalent to $\exists x$ so

$$\sim \forall x \; (M(x) \vee W(x)) = \sim \forall x \; \sim \sim (M(x) \vee W(x)) = \exists x \; \sim(M(x) \vee W(x))$$ $$= \exists x \; (\sim M(x)) \wedge (\sim W(x))$$

Therefore, there is some $x$ for which $M(x)$ and $W(x)$ fail.

In words, if we interpret $M(x)$ to mean "$x$ is a man." and $W(x)$ to mean "$x$ is a woman." The top line means that not everyone is either a man or woman. That is someone has neither gender.

The second line means there is someone who isn't a man.

The third line means there is someone who isn't a woman.

This does follow from the first line since there is someone who isn't either man or woman.

**Edit:** I am unfamiliar with "fitch". But a proof could go something like what I have above...

$$\sim \forall x \; (M(x) \vee W(x))$$
$$\sim \forall x \; \sim \sim (M(x) \vee W(x)) \qquad \mbox{replace $P$ with $\sim \sim P$}$$
$$\exists x \; \sim(M(x) \vee W(x))  \qquad \sim \forall \sim \mbox{ is equivalent with } \exists $$ 
$$\exists x \; (\sim M(x)) \wedge (\sim W(x))  \qquad \mbox{De Morgan's law}$$
$$(\sim M(A)) \wedge (\sim W(A)) \qquad \mbox{such an $A$'s existence was asserted.}$$
$$\sim M(A)$$
$$\sim W(A) \qquad \mbox{since both $M(A)$ and $W(A)$ must hold for conjunction to hold.}$$

Comment: If i were to make a proof of it using fitch, how would i go about doing it? I was under the impression that this argument was invalid.